# For with multiple in step python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

in java I can use this folowing for :

```
for(int i = 1 ; i<=100 ; i*=2)
```

now , can we implement this type of loop with python for ?

something like this : `for i in range(0,101,i*2)`

Comment: `for(int i = 0 ; i<=100 ; i*=2)` would loop forever

Comment: I quickly misread that as `+=` and posted a bogus answer. Deleted.

Comment: You can also pass a generator function as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872786/826970). Which I found to be cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: thank u very much @umutto , yes , u were right , that was very good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That loop meant to be over the powers of 2 less than 100. As noted starting with 0 would result in no progress.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(100)/math.log(2)
6.643856189774725
>>> 2**6
64
>>> 2**7
128
>>> int(math.log(100)/math.log(2))
6
```

This tells us that we can stop at `6` or `int(math.log(100)/math.log(2))`, range requires us to add one to include `6`:

```
import math

for i in (2**p for p in range(int(math.log(100)/math.log(2))+1)):
```

An example run:

```
>>> for i in (2**p for p in range(int(math.log(100)/math.log(2))+1)):
...     print i
... 
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

The literal translation of `for(int i = 1 ; i<=100 ; i*=2)` is:

```
i = 1
while i <= 100:
    # body here
    i *= 2
```

This can be turned into an generator:

```
def powers():
    i = 1
    while i <= 100:
        yield i
        i *= 2
```

which can be used like:

```
for i in powers():
    print i
```

Comment: so for in python is not as powerful as for in java/C++ :(

Comment: @Mehdi.sf Python has a for-each loop. The other type of loop is basically a quick way to write a while-loop, which you can do in Python.

Comment: You can also use shifting integers: `[1 << k for k in range(0,7)]` => `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]`

Answer (score 1):

You could define you own generator, like follows:

```
def pow2_range(max):
    i = 1
    while i < max:
        yield i
        i = i * 2

for x in pow2_range(100):
    print(i)
```

That would print:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

Answer (score 0):

`from math import log
 counter=int(log(100,2))
 for x in (2**y for y in range(1, counter+1)):
        print(x)`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for loop, it is better to use while loop for multiple increments

```
i = 0
while (i < 350):
    print(i)
    i *= 5 // multiply value = 5
```