# I'm trying to figure out how increment for loop in powers of 2

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm used to code in C and i'm currently stuck on a for loop in python.
In C the for loop looks something like `for(int i, i<=1024,i*=2){}`.
I've tried `for i in range(1,1024,*2)`,but it seems it doesn't accept *
i'm currently using

```py
Distance = 1
increment = 2
SearchRange = 1024
while Distance<SearchRange:
  Distance *=increment
```

to achieve similar results, is there anything i can do in one line in python to make it work.
I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.Please help!Thanks!

Comment: You sholud use a function called range

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31872713/11942268) not answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
>>> for i in range(15) :
...     print 1 << i, 
... 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it using while loops:

```
step = 1
i = 1
while i <= 1024:
    print(i)
    i *=2
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
```

Comment: the output of this isn't quite the same as the C version,the output of C should look like 1,2,4,8,16......but in this case i is updated twice

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it would be written:

```
for i in range(1024):
    i*=2
```

Check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop for lots of other examples.

Comment: i**2 has no effect. You're not actually updating i.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer since the question was updated:

```
iterable_range = [ 2**j for j in range(0,1024) ]
for i in iterable_range:
    print(i)
```

Using a for loop you supply an `iterable` from which the value is selected each iteration. Its not like C where index `i` is modified. So, to achieve the same in Python, you need to create an iterable of all the values.

This produces the desired:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
etc
```